# NextJs 13.2 Beta, How can I pass filters to queries?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Does anyone have any suggestions for filtering data which is fetched in a server component in Next Js beta 13.2. The data is then used across multiple components which would also need to be fed from the filtered data. I do not want to use a client component if I can help it, my data is fetched via Prisma which only works in server components.

```
export default async function Home() {
  const artists = await GetAllArtists();
  const venues = await GetAllVenues();

  const venues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

  return (
    <main className=" mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <ViewMap venues={venues} />
      <div>
        <section className="p-5">
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold p-4">Artists</h2>
          <Suspense fallback={<ArtistSkeleton />}>
            {artists && <ShowArtists artists={artists} />}
          </Suspense>
        </section>

        <section className="p-5">
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold p-4">Venues</h2>
          <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading venues...</p>}>
            {venues && <Venues venues={venues} />}
          </Suspense>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```